# Send emails via SMTP in wordpress without any plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have been trying for several days to send emails in wordpress without using plugins. Using the wp_mail function I get error 500, before I used the mail function and it worked, but I have been recommended to use this, I have also read on the official wordpress page that it is the recommended one.

The **mail.php** file is located in the root directory of wordpress. This is my code:

**Form->**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/php/processor.php" id="formulario">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mt-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="privacidad" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">He leido y acepto la <a href="/politica-de-privacidad">política de privacidad</a></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
        <button type="submit" name="submitted" id="sendForm" class="button btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar mensaje</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**mail.php->**

```
<?php

require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
   $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

   $from = 'info@tuweb.es';

   $headers = array(
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
      "Sender: $email",
      "From: Tuwebeconomica.es <$from>",
      "Reply-To: $nombre <$email>"
   );

   // wp_mail($emailTo, $asunto, $body);
   wp_mail($from, 'Nuevo mensaje de contacto desde tuweb.es', $body, $headers);

   // Se redirecciona a la página de contacto
   header('Location:' . getenv('HTTP_REFERER') . '?success=true');
}
```

As I said before I have tried the wp_mail function, mail, and phpmailer. I think I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Whats the concrete issue?

Comment: I said it in the description, it does not send the mail and I get a 500 error

Comment: Likely, because you didn't set a smtp that can send your mail.`$mail->Host = '';`. If you wanna use PHP Mail instead of SMTP, set isMail() instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you show me an example or link?

Comment: Example for what? For smtp host? Just insert the SMTP host `$mail->Host = 'your.smtp.host';`

Comment: Or just call `$mail->isMail()` instead of `$mail->isSMTP()`

Comment: No, in my code it is padded. It is smtp.ionos.com.
Also I think if there is an empty field I would not get 500 error

Comment: It depends where the error is thrown ... can you provide debugging details like an exception? The 500 is thrown because your code execution is broken, but this won't get us closer to hte error, so please, debugging details would be nice

Comment: There is no way, I have the debug activated and it does not register errors. Nor does it fall into the exception.

Comment: Details of any 500 errors will be in your web server's error log.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for an answer like this, *always* [look at the package docs first](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress), which could have saved the time you wasted.

Though you can take on all of this yourself, this isn't the best way to work with PHPMailer in Wordpress. Wordpress bundles PHPMailer, and you can make use of it instead of starting from scratch.

You need to write a hook function that intercepts the setup function that WordPress alley to configure its mailer. This lets you configure it as you like:

```php
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($mailer){
  $mailer->isSMTP();
  $mailer->Host = "mail.example.com"; // your SMTP server
  $mailer->Port = 25;
  $mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mailer->CharSet  = "utf-8";
  //etc
});
```

Once that is done, you can call [the `wp_mail` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), and it will use your config instead of WordPress' default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the wp_mail() function, it was using it correctly. I missed importing the following line:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
```

**The question is corrected**, maybe it can help someone else.